# Options to profile server side execution times in python code

Tags: python, http, profiling, multicore, execution

I've a HTTP server written in Python that accepts a large binary file (>50MB) and performs some file related computation (decryption, decompression ...) on the file. I want to get a good estimate of the the amount of time it takes to execute these operations. My python server is running on a multi CPU and multi core server on Ubuntu 11.10.

Currently I'm just doing a time diff of (`date.now()` to get the execution times for various operations.  I know there are couple of Python modules that provide profiling capabilities. However, my understanding is they are limited to small code snippets only.

What are my other options ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that cProfile is pretty solid, and definitely an improvement on using something like date.now().  Here is what cProfile produces for a comparison of a useless and slightly less useless fibonacci generator.

```
$ python -m cProfile script.py
         4113777 function calls (1371305 primitive calls) in 1.337 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cProfile.py:5(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cProfile.py:66(Profile)
        1    0.009    0.009    1.337    1.337 script.py:1(<module>)
2692508/30    1.069    0.000    1.268    0.042 script.py:3(fib)
74994/25000    0.058    0.000    0.058    0.000 script.py:9(fibber)
  1346269    0.200    0.000    0.200    0.000 {max}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {range}
```

Here is the code I used:

```
import cProfile

def fib(num):
    if num < 3:
        return max(num, 1)
    return fib(num - 1) + fib(num - 2)

fibdict = {0:1, 1:1, 2:2}
def fibber(num):
    if num not in fibdict:
        n = fibber(num - 1) + fibber(num - 2)
        fibdict[num] = n
    return fibdict[num]

a = [fib(i) for i in range(30)]
b = [fibber(i) for i in range(25000)]
```

cProfile pretty clearly tells me how slow fib is running, and gives me nice data on time per call / number of calls, as well as how much total time was spent in the method.  Obviously this is trivial/toy code, but I regularly use cProfile to get a feel for where my code is spending the most time, and I have found it very effective for non-trivial code.  I would imagine it would give you the data that you need.

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks. Any idea what the overhead of cProfile is ?

Comment: [cProfile is a c extension with reasonable overhead that makes it suitable for profiling long-running programs.](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#module-profile)  I use it pretty often, and I have never felt like it was "getting in the way" because of overhead or whatever.  The data that it gives is specific enough that I think it is valuable regardless.